# Can't train cartpole agent using DQN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

everyone, I am new to RL and trying to train a cart pole agent using DQN but I am unable to do that. here the problem is after 1000 iterations also policy is not behaving optimally and the episode ends in 10-20 steps.
here is the code I used:

```
import gymnasium as gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gym.wrappers import *
from network import DQN
import torch
from random import sample
import torch.nn as nn

class agent():
  def __init__(self):
    self.env=gym.make('CartPole-v1',render_mode="human")
    self.statespace=4
    self.epsilon=1
    self.target = DQN(4,64,32,16)
    self.current=DQN(4,64,32,16)
    self.episode=2000
    self.memory=[[],[],[],[],[]]
    self.learning_rate=0.01
    self.gamma=0.9
    self.optimizer=torch.optim.AdamW(self.current.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
    self.Memory_size=25000
    self.lossE=nn.MSELoss()
    self.train()

  def addreplay(self,sample):
        if len(self.memory[0])>self.Memory_size:
              for i in range(5):
                  self.memory[i].pop(0)
        for i in range(5):
              self.memory[i].append(sample[i])
        
              
        # state action reward next state
  def sampleminibatch(self):
        return sample([i for i in range(len(self.memory[0]))],128)
  def takeaction(self,q_value,epsilon):
        prob=np.random.random()
        if prob<epsilon:
           return np.random.randint(0,2)
        with torch.no_grad():
            action=torch.argmax(q_value).item()
            return action
  def update_network(self,minibatch,episode):
        if episode%20==0:
              self.target.load_state_dict(self.current.state_dict())
        curr_state=torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.memory[0])[minibatch].astype(np.float32))
        action=np.array(self.memory[1])[minibatch]
        next_state=torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.memory[2])[minibatch].astype(np.float32))
        reward=torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.memory[3])[minibatch].astype(np.float32))
        done=torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.memory[4])[minibatch].astype(np.float32))
        
        curr_value=self.current(curr_state)
        curr_value=curr_value[range(len(action)),action]
      #   print("here")
      #   print(curr_state)
      #   print(curr_value)
        curr_value=torch.unsqueeze(curr_value,1)
      #   print(curr_value)

        with torch.no_grad():
             value=torch.max(self.target(next_state),1)[0]
             target_value=torch.mul(value,done)
             rew_target=torch.unsqueeze(reward + self.gamma * target_value, 1)
        

        
        loss= self.lossE(curr_value,rew_target)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        return loss
        
  def train(self):
        for i in range(self.episode):
            loss=[]
            total_reward=0
            self.env.reset()
            self.env.render()
            terminated=False
            truncated=False
            self.epsilon=self.epsilon-0.001
            while not (terminated or truncated):
                self.state=torch.tensor(self.env.state,dtype=torch.float32)
                with torch.no_grad():
                     action=self.takeaction(self.current(self.state),self.epsilon)
                observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info=self.env.step(action)
                sample=[self.env.state,action,observation,reward,not terminated]
                self.addreplay(sample)
                total_reward+=reward
                if len(self.memory[0])>128:
                      loss.append(self.update_network(self.sampleminibatch(),i).item())
            if len(loss)>0:
                  print("loss: "+str(sum(loss)/len(loss))+" episode :"+str(i)+" total_reward: "+str(total_reward))
                      
cartpole=agent()
```

here is the code for Network:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn 
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input,hidden1,hidden2,hidden3):
        super(DQN,self).__init__()
        self.layer1=nn.Linear(input,hidden1)
        self.relu=nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2=nn.Linear(hidden1,hidden2)
        self.layer3=nn.Linear(hidden2,hidden3)
        self.layer4=nn.Linear(hidden3,2)
        self.loss=nn.MSELoss()
    def forward(self,input):
        out=self.layer1(input)
        out=self.relu(out)
        out=self.layer2(out)
        out=self.relu(out)
        out=self.layer3(out)
        out=self.relu(out)
        out=self.layer4(out)
        return out
```

I am trying to train this from past week and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried changing the number of episodes, decay rate, learning rate, number of layers, and it size but none of it seems to work. can anyone direct me in the right direction?